What does this kubectl log mean: "Defaulted container xxx out of: xxx, xxx (init) "?
When I run kubectl exec -ti "$1" -- sh to enter into my docker contains, sometime I see the log shows "Defaulted container xxx out of: xxx, xxx (init) ", e.g.
//enter into my php-fpm container
Defaulted container "php-fpm" out of: php-fpm, init-php (init)
//Or mysql container
Defaulted container "mysql" out of: mysql, git-sync (init)
//Or
Defaulted container "httpd-php-container" out of: httpd-php-container

But sometime I don't see that log, especially when kubectl exec -ti "$1" -- bash to enter into my nodejs contains.
What do these logs mean exactly?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
